Computing degree of $x$ map for elliptic curve given by Weierstrass equation
Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve given by the Weierstrass equation
$$
y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6
$$
I want to calculate the degree of the map
$$
\varphi\colon E\to\mathbb{P}^1\qquad\quad[x,y,1]\mapsto[x,1]
$$
I first tried to calculate the degree of $K(E)/\varphi^*K(\mathbb{P}^1)$ but this got me nowhere. I then tried to use the fact that $\text{deg}(\varphi)=\sum_{P\in f^{-1}(O)}e_O=\text{ord}_O(Z/X)$ for $O=[0,1,0]$ but I don't know how to proceed further.

I think your second approach is feasible: you have to compute the order of the pole of $x$ at $O$. Here's a (hopefully) easier strategy. The map $\varphi$ has only finitely many ramification points. Avoiding these, then we can assume that $e_{\varphi}(P) = 1$ for all $P$ in the formula $\deg(\varphi) = \sum_{P \in \varphi^{-1}(Q)} e_{\varphi}(P)$. Assuming we're in this case, the question becomes: given a fixed value $x_0$, how many corresponding $y$-values are there that give solutions of $y^2+a_1x_0y+a_3y=x_0^3+a_2x_0^2+a_4x_0+a_6$?

@ViktorVaughn I don't understand how we know $\varphi$ has only finitely many ramification points.

Correct me, if I'm wrong, but won't $\phi^$ go the other way from $K(\Bbb{P}^1)$ to $K(E)$? After all, an element of a function field of a curve $C$ is a rational map $f:C\to K$. We can then precompose it with $\phi$ to get a rational map $\phi(f):E\to K$.

That way the degree of the field extension is simply $[K(x,y):K(x)]=2$ because $y$ is a root of an irreducible quadratic over $K(x)$.

Two comments up it should read $\phi^*(f)=f\circ\phi:E\to K$.

@JyrkiLahtonen, yes you're right. I will edit the question. Thanks.
